# How to apply percentage discount to whole cart total in Magento?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, discount

I have a issue like, I have to create a promotion rule which gives percentage total on cart total.
Currently Magneto offers promotion rule on cart per item. But I have different scenario like

```
cart item total+extra fee = cart total - percentage discount
```

Current Magento rule calculates like

```
cart item total = cart total - percentage discount
```

I need this to implement with coupon code only.

Help will be appreciated, 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules` you just need to specify the percentage amount you want to apply discount with respect to total and set it to `No Coupon`.

Comment: Okay,just give me some time I will get back to you regarding this.

Comment: There is no "Cart Percentage" discount in Magento actually... maybe with some modules...